# use Tesseract with visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract 3.02 and laptonica 1.68 with visual studio 2012. I have added all the includes and the DLL's to the property manager.

1. Debug Property Pages >> C/C++ >> General >> Additional include directories >> **C:\Tesseract-OCR\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)**
2. Linker >> General >> Additional Library Directories >> **C:\Tesseract-OCR\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)**
3. Linker >> Input >> 
   giflib416-static-mtdll-debug
   libjpeg8c-static-mtdll-debug
   liblept168d
   liblept168-static-mtdll-debug
   libpng143-static-mtdll-debug
   libtiff394-static-mtdll-debug
   zlib125-static-mtdll-debug

---

And when I build a hello world program it gives the linker error: **LNK1104: cannot open file 'giflib416-static-mtdll-debug.obj'**

But the library directory is already added to the property manager. Any idea about what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of things in the Linker >> Input should be .lib files right?  I think you need the .lib extension (and the .lib files need to exist)

Comment: yes. thanks a lot. that was the issue. sorry for posting such a lame question